# regexp in js(jquery) reverse googlemaps url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Just what to know how to use regexp to get the zoomLevel,Latitude & Longitude from a raw googlemaps link.
The idea is that I just put the raw googlemaps v3 link in my cms, my problem is to use this link when I need to present it on my cms page with a custommarker. Need some reverse parsing of the gmap link.

All inputs are appreciated.

The raw google link is this: ( would like the zoomLevel,Latitude & Longitude somehow - perhaps with regexp )
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=barcelona+spain&hl=en&ll=41.385052,2.184906&spn=0.336927,0.883026&sll=57.029521,9.933014&sspn=0.488772,1.766052&t=h&hnear=Barcelona,+Province+of+Barcelona,+Catalonia,+Spain&z=11

so the answer :

```
str= 'the googlemaps link';
zoomRegex= str.match(/&z=([^&]+)/);
zoomlevel = zoomRegex[1];

var ll = new Array();
LatLongRegex= str.match(/&ll=([^&]+)/);
LatLong = LatLongRegex[1];
ll = LatLong.split(',');

console.log("lat:" + ll[0]+ ", long:" + ll[1] +" - Zoomlevel:"+zoomlevel);​
```

Think this is it THANKS. 
Does it need improvements ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse out different variables of the query string like so:

```
str = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=barcelona+spain&hl=en&ll=41.385052,2.184906&spn=0.336927,0.883026&sll=57.029521,9.933014&sspn=0.488772,1.766052&t=h&hnear=Barcelona,+Province+of+Barcelona,+Catalonia,+Spain&z=11";

matches = str.match(/&z=([^&]+)/);
zoomlevel = matches[1];
```

This example is for zoom level, I'm assuming the lat/long variable is `ll`. If you need the latitude and longitude separately you can `split` it at the comma.